# Code Inside KeyListener Methods not Working

Tags: java, rotation, keylistener

I'm trying to rotate my drawn object by changing variables when keys are pressed. Nothing happens when I press the buttons. I think something may have gone wrong.

I also have a main class where I make an instance of the JPanel.

```
public class Move extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    public Move() {
        addKeyListener(this);//adds the interface to the class to be used
        setFocusable(true);//sets focus, allowing the use of keylistener methods
    }
    private int c, d;
    private int a = 60;//left corner of whatever
    private int b = 60;
    private Point point1 = new Point(a+50,b+10);
    private Point point2 = new Point(a+50+15,b+10+20);
    private Point point3 = new Point(a+50-15,b+10+20);
    private Point point4 = new Point(a+50+15,b+10-20);
    private Point point5 = new Point(a+50-15,b+10-20);
    private Point point6 = new Point(a+25,b+10);
    private Point point7 = new Point(a-25,b);
    private Point point8 = new Point(a-25,b+20);
    private int x1[] = {(int) point1.getX(),(int) point2.getX(), (int) point3.getX()};
    private int y1[] = {(int) point1.getY(), (int) point2.getY(), (int) point3.getY()};
    private int n = 3;
    private Polygon p1 = new Polygon(x1,y1,n);
    private int x2[] = {(int) point1.getX(),(int) point4.getX(), (int) point5.getX()};
    private int y2[] = {(int) point1.getY(),(int) point4.getY(), (int) point5.getY()};
    private Polygon p2 = new Polygon(x2,y2,n);
    private int x3[] = {(int) point6.getX(),(int) point7.getX(), (int) point8.getX()};
    private int y3[] = {(int) point6.getY(),(int) point7.getY(), (int) point8.getY()};
    private Polygon p3 = new Polygon(x3,y3,n);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawOval(a, b, 100, 20);
        g.drawPolygon(p1);
        g.drawPolygon(p2);
        g.drawPolygon(p3);
        g.fillPolygon(p1);
        g.fillPolygon(p2);
        g.fillPolygon(p3);
        g.fillOval(a, b, 100, 20);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
            if(c==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                double x1 = point1.getX() - 160;
                double y1 = point1.getY() - 80;

                //APPLY ROTATION
                double temp_x1 = x1 * Math.sin(1.57);
                double temp_y1 = y1 * Math.cos(1.57);

                //TRANSLATE BACK
                point1.setLocation(temp_x1 + 160, temp_y1 + 80);
            }
            else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                point1.setLocation(point1.getX()+100, point1.getY());
                screen.repaint();
            }
            else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_UP){

            }
            else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){

            }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

}

I tried moving my code in graphics component into the the keylistener to check if the problem was with the key listener but when I did, the keylistener drew when I pressed a key. So at this point I'm not sure where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The instances of `Point` you have as coordinates for the points of the polygons are not related to the actual coordinates in the polygon class since you put the coordinates of the points into arrays and initialize the polygons with them, but the value of the numbers in the array won't change when you change the points coordinates.

To translate a `polygon` you have to change the values in the `polygon.xpoints` and `polygon.ypoints` arrays.

Everything else should work quite fine.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I've tried changing `point1.getX()` to `polygon.xpoints[0]` but I don't think that's the correct way. How exactly do I go about changing the values in `polygon.xpoints` ? I have also tried `p1.xpoints[0] = (int) temp_x1` but this does not work either.

Comment: Nevermind I somehow got it to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: sorry, it was very late so I went to sleep